# Unable to set UITableView Section title using JSON data

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, uitableview

My Parse cloud code is returning JSON data to my iOS app, and I want to set the section title of my `UITableView` to the `Search Term` property that it's returning. I've tried to reference the `matchCenterDictionary` in order to select that key specifically, but it just shows `(null)` as the section title.

Referencing the dictionary in this way has worked perfectly fine when it comes to setting the text labels of the cells, so I'm not sure why it's not working for this purpose.

MatchCenterViewController.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Parse/Parse.h>
#import "AsyncImageView.h"
#import "SearchViewController.h"

@interface MatchCenterViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource>

@property (nonatomic) IBOutlet NSString *itemSearch;

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *imageURLs;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *matchingCategoryCondition;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *matchingCategoryLocation;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSNumber *matchingCategoryMaxPrice;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSNumber *matchingCategoryMinPrice;

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *matchCenterArray;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSDictionary *matchCenterDictionary;

@end
```

MatchCenterViewController.m:

```
#import "MatchCenterViewController.h"
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MatchCenterViewController () <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>
@property (nonatomic, strong) UITableView *matchCenter;
@end

@implementation MatchCenterViewController


- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
    }
    return self;
}


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.matchCenter = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds style:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle];
    self.matchCenter.frame = CGRectMake(0,50,320,self.view.frame.size.height-200);
    _matchCenter.dataSource = self;
    _matchCenter.delegate = self;
    [self.view addSubview:self.matchCenter];

    self.matchCenterArray = [[NSArray alloc] init];
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    self.matchCenterArray = [[NSArray alloc] init];

    [PFCloud callFunctionInBackground:@"MatchCenter"
                       withParameters:@{
                                        @"test": @"Hi",
                                        }
                                block:^(NSDictionary *result, NSError *error) {

                                    if (!error) {
                                         self.matchCenterArray = [result objectForKey:@"Top 3"];

                                        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                                            [_matchCenter reloadData];
                                        });

                                        NSLog(@"Test Result: '%@'", result);
                                    }
                                }];
}




- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}




//the part where i setup sections and the deleting of said sections

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 21.0f;
}



- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    UIView *headerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 21)];
    headerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];

    NSString *searchTerm = [_matchCenterDictionary objectForKey:@"Search Term"];

    UILabel *headerLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(8, 0, 250, 21)];
    headerLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", searchTerm];
    headerLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:[UIFont systemFontSize]];
    headerLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    headerLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    [headerView addSubview:headerLabel];

    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    button.tag = section + 1000;
    button.frame = CGRectMake(300, 2, 17, 17);
    [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"31-circle-x"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(deleteButtonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [headerView addSubview:button];
    return headerView;
}



- (IBAction)deleteButtonPressed:(UIButton *)sender {
//    NSInteger section = sender.tag - 1000;
//    [self.objects removeObjectAtIndex:section];
//    [self.tableView deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:section] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
//    
//    // reload sections to get the new titles and tags
//    NSInteger sectionCount = [self.objects count];
//    NSIndexSet *indexes = [NSMutableIndexSet indexSetWithIndexesInRange:NSMakeRange(0, sectionCount)];
//    [self.tableView reloadSections:indexes withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
}






- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
     return [self.matchCenterArray count];
}



- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Initialize cell
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (!cell) {
        // if no cell could be dequeued create a new one
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    // populate dictionary with results
    NSDictionary *matchCenterDictionary= [self.matchCenterArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    // title of the item
    cell.textLabel.text = [matchCenterDictionary objectForKey:@"Title"];
    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12];

    // price of the item
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"$%@", [matchCenterDictionary objectForKey:@"Price"]];
    cell.detailTextLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0/255.0f green:127/255.0f blue:31/255.0f alpha:1.0f];


    NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[matchCenterDictionary objectForKey:@"Image URL"]]];
    [[cell imageView] setImage:[UIImage imageWithData:imageData]];



    return cell;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


/*
#pragma mark - Navigation

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/

@end
```

JSON being returned:

```
    {
    "Top 3" =     (
                {
            "Image URL" = "http://thumbs4.ebaystatic.com/m/maPdKVZiQtK7oHcR-PY81sg/140.jpg";
            "Item URL" = "http://www.ebay.com/itm/Samsung-Galaxy-S5-SM-G900P-16GB-Black-Sprint-Brand-New-s5-LTE-ESN-BAD-/261503613519?pt=Cell_Phones";
            Price = "390.0";
            "Search Term" = "moto x 16gb";
            Title = "Samsung Galaxy S5 SM-G900P 16GB Black (Sprint) Brand New s5 LTE *ESN BAD*";
        },
                {
            "Image URL" = "http://thumbs4.ebaystatic.com/m/mkF9PJ_sT3_yGR_3AVM8TAA/140.jpg";
            "Item URL" = "http://www.ebay.com/itm/HDC-Galaxy-S5-SM-G900-Unlocked-Smartphone-White-16-GB-GSM-WCDMA-1-7GHz-Octa-Core-/281356592227?pt=Cell_Phones";
            Price = "279.99";
            "Search Term" = "moto x 16gb";
            Title = "HDC Galaxy S5 SM-G900 Unlocked Smartphone White 16 GB GSM WCDMA 1.7GHz Octa Core";
        },
                {
            "Image URL" = "http://thumbs1.ebaystatic.com/m/mkwGBy79W6XidMm0ZALMthw/140.jpg";
            "Item URL" = "http://www.ebay.com/itm/SAMSUNG-GALAXY-S5-SM-G900P-16GB-sprint-READ-DESCRIPTION-/141313501036?pt=Cell_Phones";
            Price = "379.0";
            "Search Term" = "moto x 16gb";
            Title = "SAMSUNG GALAXY S5 SM-G900P - 16GB (sprint)- READ DESCRIPTION !!!";
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: What is `_matchCenterDictionary`? There is no ivar or property for this. How is it set?

Comment: @rmaddy, that was my attempt at making it a public property, I must have accidentally deleted it from the header file before posting, I've edited my post.

Comment: OK but where is it set? Is it set?

Comment: Now that I look at it again, I realize I haven't set it. What would be the correct way to do that?

Comment: That's up to you. It's your data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow Adrian's instructions (use the self.matchCenterArray).

Then change this:

```
NSString *searchTerm = [self.matchCenterArray objectForKey:@"Search Term"];
```

to this, for example:

```
NSString *searchTerm = [[self.matchCenterArray firstObject] objectForKey:@"Search Term"];
```

The search term is in each NSDictionary in the array.. so you need to first retrieve the firstObject for instance.

Answer (score 1):

You should be using self.matchCenterArray instead of _matchCenterDictionary

The way you would have to do it is by parsing the data.

```
NSString *searchTerm = [[self.matchCenterArray objectAtIndex:section] objectForKey:@"Search Term"];
```

Comment: This causes the app to crash stating `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'`, which is weird, because it doesn't give me that error when I reference the array in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

Comment: This means self.matchCenterArray does not have data in it. I would remove the self.matchCenterArray = new array from viewDidAppear. Also you dont have to do dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), in block to reload data in table. you can just call the reloadData function directly

Comment: He actually **does** need to use the main queue since the block is running on the background and the UI on the main thread..